# Start an Activity based on parameter passed from JavaScript interface

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I want to open a new activity when I tap on a link in my `WebView`, but I don't know how to create a method passing an `Object` variable to make a dynamic method. That's why I do it this way actually:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    public Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void toAbout(){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class));
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void toTwitch(){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Twitch.class));
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void toNews(){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, News.class));
    }

    (much more methods like these for specific classes) ...

}
```

HTML/JS:

```
<div class="entry" onclick="toTwitch();">Twitch</div>
<div class="entry" onclick="toAbout();">About</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toTwitch() { 
        Android.toTwitch();
    }   
    function toAbout(input) { 
        Android.toAbout();
    }
</script>
```

MainActivity.java `onCreate`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        // Caching
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    }
```

**Isn't there a way to make just one single method instead of dozens (`toAbout()`, `toTwitch`, `toNews()`, etc.) that is more dynamic?**

Comment: Comparing to the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html), I don't see any issue, but perhaps try using the passed context `mContext`, instead of `MainActivity.this`?

Comment: It works, but the thing is that I don't want to create like 10 methods for each activity (page) I want to navigate like with `public void toAbout()`, `public void toNews()`, ..., ..., ... (there is much more). Isn't there an alternative to make just one single dynamic method? Because it seems I can't pass the object. @AndrewT.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the question. But after the edit, now it's clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry to asked that so unclearly. Do you know any solution? @AndrewT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android JavaScript interface supports parameter passing.

You can create a generic method which accepts `String`, get the respective `Class` and use it on `startActivity()`. Note that you have to use **fully-qualified name** of the `Activity`, which means including the package name (e.g. `com.example.About`).

Inside `WebAppInterface`,

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void openActivity(String activityName) {
    String packageName = "com.example";
    try {
        Class activityClass = Class.forName(packageName + "." + activityName);
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "invalid activity name: " + activityName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

On HTML/JS,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toTwitch() { 
        Android.openActivity('Twitch');
    }   
    function toAbout() { 
        Android.openActivity('About');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much! It works now. Just one question: This is my first Android app and I'm very used to PHP/HTML/CSS/JS/JQuery, etc. Is this like a "bad way" to make an app, because I'm just using the WebView to display content and to navigate? I just have Texts, Images, CSS in my app and I don't have any buttons or input fields. And the downside of course is that there is no native feedback when I tap on a link inside the WebView.

Comment: I can't say anything about that (I always do native app until now), but take a look at [hybrid mobile app](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a question about how `WebView` interact with native apps. OK, I explain here in details in case others run into the same question.

**First**, create an inner class which interacts with the current `Activity` like this:

```
private final class JsReturnHomeObj {
    JsReturnHomeObj() {
    }

    public void returnHomeOnClick() {

        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(PayWapActivity.this,
                        HomeActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Second**, set your `WebView` support this `JavaScript` action:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_pay_wap_webview);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsReturnHomeObj(), "js_return_home");
```

**At last**, call this method by `JavaScript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toTwitch() { 
        js_return_home.returnHomeOnClick();
    }
</script>
```

I hope you are inspired.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question (just like me in the first place). They said that the current code works, but they want to have a single function to start `Activity` dynamically.

Comment: @AndrewT. If so, I agreed wih your codes of  `java reflection`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts anyway! I'm sorry to be that unclear at first. @SilentKnight